# The differences between normal jar and `original` jar when calling `mvn package`?

Tags: maven, jar, compilation, package

I'm following maven tutorial from springsource [here](http://spring.io/guides/gs/maven/), and after calling `mvn package` commmand, we get the below three outcomes.

For the shaded jar package, we can understand it as an [all-dependencies-icluded version](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) for the jar.

My question is, what is the differences between the normal jar and the `original` jar when calling `mvn package` ?

[image]

Comment: Normally there should only be two jars created (one which is shaded and one which isn't). If you are following the tutorial exactly then I think what you are seeing are leftovers from previous builds (which is why you are seeing three jars). If you execute `mvn clean package` what do you see in the target directory?

Comment: @DB5 Doing `mvn clean package` creates three files.

Comment: can you add your maven-shade-plugin configuration from your pom to your question? By default it should not create three jars.

Comment: It is in the tutorial DB5 http://spring.io/guides/gs/maven/
Anyway, I upload the same file here https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6194904/2014/pom.xml

Comment: Unfortunately when I use that exact same pom I only have two jars in the target directory. I have no idea where the 3rd jar is coming from. What is the content of the three jars (if you open them with winzip or something similar)? Also just double checking, but if you physically delete the target folder within Windows and then execute mvn package you still get three jars?

Comment: Yeah, they are two files now when we remove the `target` folder manually. Now I am messed up with the tutorial ^^ When was the `appId-version-shaded.jar` created then?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63462/discussion-between-nam-g-vu-and-db5).

Answer (score 6):

The shaded jar is the jar with all the dependencies that are in your pom.xml. The original, is the jar without that dependencies, the jar that would be generated if that shade plugin would not be there

Comment: So what is the difference between `original-appId-version.jar` with  `appId-version.jar` ?

Comment: No idea, there should be two jars only